# passing directly "object literal param"_{ }_ in WeakMap() works , although no reference to it

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, weakmap

I noticed something, when i create an object and set it in **WeakMap()**, it is stored within **WeakMap()**, but when i re-assign this variable with value "null", *"Grabage collector"* remove this key from **WeakMap()**, because no reference to it.

```js
let object1 = { name: "A" };
const map1 = new WeakMap();
map1.set(object1, "Apple");
console.log(map1.has(object1)); // true
object1 = null; // now garbage collector will remove the object from WeakMap
```

**The Question Here:** when i pass an object literal directly as a param in **WeakMap()**, why this object wouldn't been removed? because it hasn't any reference for it

```js
map1.set({ name: "D" }, "Direct");
//Why map accept this param, although no reference for it
```

UPDATE: it would been removed as well in case you pass literal object directly to `WeakMap`

Comment: Why do you say the object wouldn't be removed? There are no other references to it, it should be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: What makes you think it won't be removed?

Comment: Thank You so much, I thought it won't been removed, because it accept it as parameter
but it will been removed as well!
now make sense